SwiftUI - How to get a list or loop over the properties of a built-in struct, like UnitPoint?
I am building an interface where I want to allow the user to select an anchor point for rotation - from a Picker for now.
The expected values are of UnitPoint type, which allows for options like .topLeading, .bottomTrailing, .bottom, etc. - similar to Alignment options.
I figured out how to manually make these options available in a Picker, by tagging them as a UnitPoint:
Text("Top Left").tag(UnitPoint.topLeading)

But I cannot figure out how I can loop over all defined UnitPoint anchors, something like:
ForEach(UnitPoint.allAnchors, id:\.self) { anchor in
   Text(anchor.name).tag(id)
}

From what I can see in the SwiftUI docs, UnitPoint conforms to Hashable, but I am not sure if that's something I can use for looping purposes. Normally, it would be something like CaseIterable or Identifiable, etc.
Basically, I am trying to get a list of values like you would get in the code autocomplete popup in Xcode when you have to provide a UnitPoint value.

I tried various ways using a Mirror to get a list of its properties/structure, but it's always empty:
ForEach(Mirror(reflecting: UnitPoint()).children.map {$0.label}) { anchor in
    ... //output is always an empty array []
}

Here's the simplified code I have so far:
struct AnchorPicker: View {
    
    @State private var selectedAnchor: UnitPoint = .topLeading
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Picker(selection: $selectedAnchor) {
            Text("topLeading").tag(UnitPoint.topLeading)
            Text("bottomLeading").tag(UnitPoint.bottomLeading)
            
            //Loop would go here, replacing the manual options above
            // ForEach( ... ) { anchor in
            //  Text(anchor.name)
            // }
            
        } label: {
            Text("Select an anchor")
        }
    }
}

#Preview("Anchor Picker") {
    AnchorPicker()
}

Looking forward to suggestions.

This is currently not possible. I'd just hard code each point.

\.self isn't a valid id it needs to be a keypath to a unique identifier property that it can use to track inserts/moves/deletes. You might need to wrap the data in your own type to get that, i.e. transform it.

@Sweeper Thanks, I ended up hard coding all the values. A little dirty, but it works.
